# How to check where rows in a dataframe are missing?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a rather lengthy data manipulation project and one of the datasets that I merged into my dataframe has a lesser length of 96 rows (6963 vs 6867), and I cannot for the life of me figure out where.

[image: picture_of_dataframe]

Checking .head() and .tail() shows that the all datasets in the dataframe start and end on the same date, but I have reason to think its interfering with my other analysis, for obvious reasons.

Checking `crypto_df['doge_close,'doge_open']` shows they are the correct length of 6963 (total # of dates in dataframe), but I cannot find where in the dataset the rows are missing.

Is there a function to check this? I don't think I'm being specific enough on google, if there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for rows that have NaN, do this:
`crypto_df[crypto_df['doge_close'].isnull ()]`

Comment: @Falcon crypto_df['doge_close,'doge_open', 'doge_volume'] have few non null values (it could be None, NaN or na). As Yashar pointed use 'isnull'. You can also use 'isna'